# iOS pageviewcontroller disable swipe

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have an application that has three navigation controllers in a UIPageViewController.

```
                                              |-> Detail View
                      |-- nav 1 -> root view -|
                      |                       |-> Search View
UIPageViewController -|-- nav 2 -> root view
                      | 
                      |-- nav 3 -> root view
```

Nav 1, 2, and 3 all have views that branch out from there. The issue is that once I open a subview of one of the navigation controllers, I can still swipe between the 3 separate navigation controllers. I want to disable swipe if I'm > 1 layer deep (detail or search view) of a navigation controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why having 3 Navigation controllers ?

Put your PageViewController inside your NavigationController. You don't need to disable your swipe gesture like this.

But if you really want to have this architecture, you can remove the data source. Without `dataSource`, the pageViewController does not slides. Set again the dataSource to enable swipe again.

```
// Methods of the data source are called in response to gesture-based navigation.
// If the value of this property is nil, then gesture-based navigation is disabled.
```

Comment: Because then there's one navigation bar for all three views. I want one navigation bar for each view.

Comment: If I set `dataSource` to `nil`, I get this error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: [views count] == 3'`

Comment: It is not supposed to happen… Do you have created a variable `views` somewhere in your code ? Else, consider using the *WOW* solution. you can keep the gestureRecognizer to the view and set `true` or `false` to the `enabled` property of the recognizer.

Comment: Not sure what changed, but I tried this again after looking at Apple's docs and this worked. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear: I set `dataSource` to `nil` in my `prepareForSegue` function, and then reset it back to `UIPageViewController` (parent self) in the child `viewWillAppear`